# How do I get a partial string in an Exchange 2003 Recipient Policy?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

I'd like to set a rule for email names that is the following:

lastname.first three letters of firstname @ aso . com

Here's what I got:

[image]

As you can see, it's exactly what I want except the firstname is being written in full, I want only the first three letters of the first name. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

To get a partial string, put the number of characters you want in between the percent sign and the letter signifying the name component.

For example, `%s.%3g.@acme-widgets.com` gives the whole of `%s` (sn), a period (.) and the first 3 characters of `%g` (givenName).